# `Invalid authority type` when trying to Lock an NFT I own via CPIBuilders on anchor

Tags: metaplex, cpi, mpl-token-metadata

I am trying to call this instruction to lock an NFT.

```
        LockCpiBuilder::new(&ctx.accounts.metadata_program)
            .authority(&ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info()) //authority
            .token_owner(Some(&ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info()))
            .token(&ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info())
            .mint(&ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info())
            .metadata(&ctx.accounts.metadata_account.to_account_info())
            .edition(Some(&ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info()))
            .token_record(Some(&ctx.accounts.token_record.to_account_info()))
            .payer(&ctx.accounts.admin.to_account_info())
            .system_program(&ctx.accounts.system_program)
            .sysvar_instructions(&ctx.accounts.sysvar_program)
            .spl_token_program(Some(&ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info()))
            .authorization_rules_program(Some(&ctx.accounts.auth_rules_program))
            .authorization_rules(Some(&ctx.accounts.auth_rules.to_account_info()))
            .lock_args(LockArgs::V1 {
                authorization_data: None,
            })
            .invoke()?;
```

The call is failing and these are the [program logs](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3VNUh9XrdKdFLojnsp5K1XadLYartofHK2PFJqJpi6YR1kYzQfFfLWyTfxKkjqGHKrsWDWe8DydNiSq67enV1VzN?cluster=devnet)

```
#1
Unknown Program (MZp46X3Fdg3B9Neb1oFXmeuLaeZhf52McEjxL6hAJBb) Instruction

> Program logged: "Instruction: Initialize"
> Program logged: "freeze authority Some(9gafE5oBZnyTRXZD2WbcwJW5pfZ5WQXWJDLtCcTXMsBr)"
> Program invoked: Token Metadata Program
  > Program logged: "IX: Lock"
  > Program logged: "Invalid authority type"
  > Program consumed: 17579 of 162916 compute units
  > Program returned error: "custom program error: 0x9e"
> Program consumed: 54663 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: "custom program error: 0x9e"
>
```

Comment: have you set admin as `delegate authority` before locking the nft?

Comment: Turns out that was the issue. I had to delegate first.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're seeing `0x9e`, decimal 158, is `InvalidAuthorityType`: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/64ba3cb8937dff668a5e1926d3beaf694ea6f3dc/programs/token-metadata/program/src/error.rs#L625

So maybe the `admin` account you're providing isn't the correct authority on the NFT